# Build Automatically versus Build Manually

Tags: xpages

"Build Automatically" is a real pain when you are working on a slow server because sometimes when you change one small item of code (or even just look at it) the whole project seems to rebuild - which can take many minutes and breaks the database in the mean time.

If I disable "Build Automatically" and build individual elements manually how much do I need to do?

For example if I modify a custom control do I need to rebuild the "parent" Xpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that if you turn off "Build Automatically" you need to rebuild at some point after you have modified any Custom Controls, XPages, or Java code embedded in your application. This does not mean after each one, but clearly before you can test the changes.

You do not seem to need to rebuild after modifying a theme, css, or JS script library (client or server). And, of course, changes to traditional design elements (forms, views, agents, pages, etc.) do not require a rebuild.

Best idea is to work and test locally (or on a local server) and update the server as needed. I do that with Build Automatically turned off.

/Newbs

Answer (score 3):

"Build Automatically" causes a build to be performed on every save operation (on buildable design elements). A manual build does the exact same thing, but only when you tell it to. In other words, disabling this setting doesn't force you to build each design element separately... it just increases your productivity while you're developing, as a build is only performed when you decide you're ready to test.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to work locally if you want to keep the 'build automatically' option enabled and then replicate the database back up to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I do all my xPages development locally, the only reason to not develop locally as I see it is if you need to "login" to your application, which must be done on server.

if you switch off build automatically, (and also tick the box to not show a warning "if you have not build") then you might easy forget to build and can start get pretty insane before you realize that you have to build before you can see your changes.

Turn off automatic build and learn a new command: CTRL-B + CTRL-S