# XPage gets signed by an ID used previously

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

We use shared development Notes IDs for some databases because the application breaks immediately if [one XPage is signed with different ID than others](http://linqed.eu/?p=110). You might also get

> Error 403 HTTP Web Server: You are forbidden to perform this operation

like I just got.

The problem with using multiple IDs is that XPages get signed by wrong ID. When I switch ID and edit an XPage sometimes it (and occasionally other XPages) gets signed by the ID I used previously. When I select the XPage from the list after that and click the "Sign" button it is signed with the ID I'm using.

Anyone else fighting with this problem and found any solutions? I have been using Windows 7 and now Windows 8 and Designer 9. I think this is quite serious bug.

Answer (score 4):

Turn off Build Automatically. I also have found that to effectively switch IDs I have to shut down and restart Notes using the second ID.

Comment: OK so to be able to use Build Automatically I need to shut down Designer each time I switch ID :-(. I use Build Automatically because if I use just Build I have to build two times which is an interesting bug/feature also.

Comment: From what I have read here previously, if you use Build Automatically, additional items get signed and rebuilt besides the one(s) you updated. I have just gotten into the habit of restarting and hitting Build when done making my changes. Not sure if I ever did it more than once however.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131599/build-automatically-versus-build-manually?rq=1

Comment: Very interesting if can manage with only one build. See f.e. this http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-build-project-investigations/ "It is the second Build that creates the class files for the XPages and Custom Controls".

Comment: Yes, if you have Build Automatically switched off, open a database in Designer, make a change and do a build, it only does an incremental build. You need a second build to do a full build. Personally though I would still recommend switching Build Automatically off. If you're working together on an app and a build happens, it can affect global objects. Certainly if you make a change to a managed bean Java class and build, it removes the current bean from memory, which can cause other people to have problems testing their changes.

Comment: Paul, that might explain why the debugBar always gets corrupt when a second person opens the NSD in Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Different IDs signing design elements is only really a problem if you use sessionAsSigner. If a webpage uses components signed by different IDs, sessionAsSigner then just gives up because it doesn't know which signer to use. In SSJS it throws an Error 500, in Java it works for a while but you may find your server crashes.

When I'm working on an application with another developer, my preference is to work on a standalone copy and either use source control to merge changes across or manually merge using Package Explorer's "Compare With > Each Other..." option. Selecting the XPages node in each database and comparing with each other is a reasonable alternative to source control for transferring changes back to a core template, once I'm happy with my feature change.

Cameron Gregor has been doing some work on an OpenNTF project called Dora to avoid source control thinking traditional Domino design elements have been updated when they've just been accessed or signed. Sean Cull has done quite a bit of documentation on source control in Domino as well.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. For me it would make sense if sessionAsSigner would always use the signer of the component (XPage or Custom Control) where the code is running.

Comment: The problem then comes where the code on the XPage or Custom Control (whether SSJS or EL) calls code in a Script Library or custom Java class. :-)

Comment: That does not seem to be a problem in LotusScript world. There you can actually choose if it runs using agent or script library signer.